# My dropdown is getting only one item from the fornext loop

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I am creating widget that will allow a user to select an item from a dropdown.
What I have come up with is a widget that has a a dropdown that shows the first item. The rest are printed to the screen like this: 
Item 2
;
Item 3
;Enter a new event name. (label)
input box

```
<?php

/* Plugin Name: Events Widget
  Description: This widget allows the user to select an Event name.
  Version: 0.5
  Author: Dan Statham
  Author URI:
  License: GPLv2
 */
function gdd_Events_load_widgets() {
    write_log('gdd _Events_load_widgets');
}// gdd_Events_load_widgets

// Register the widget
function my_register_custom_widget() {
    register_widget( 'gdd_Events_load_widgets' );
} //  echo('registerd');

function submit(){
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $selected_val = $_POST['Color'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable
     echo "You have selected :" .$selected_val;  // Displaying Selected Value
}

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_register_custom_widget' );  


// The widget class
class gdd_Events_load_widgets extends WP_Widget {
    function gdd_Events_Widget() {
        /* Widget settings. */
        $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'event', 
                    'description' => __('Allow the user to select an Event name.', 'event') );

        /* Widget control settings. */
        $control_ops = array( 'width' => 200, 'height' => 150, 'id_base' => 'gdd_Events_Widget' );

        /* Create the widget. */
        $this->WP_Widget( 'Event', __('Event Name', 'event'), $widget_ops, $control_ops );
    } // function gdd_Events_Widget
    // Main constructor
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(                
                // base ID of the widget
                'gdd_Events_Widget',
                // name of the widget
                __('Event Name dropdown', 'events'),
                // widget options
                array(
                    'description' => __('Select the Event name.',
                            'events')
               )
        ); //parent __construct()
    }//function __construct()

    public function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['eventsdropdown'] = strip_tags($new_instance['eventsdropdown']);
        return $instance;
    }
// function update

    public function widget($args, $instance) {
        // kick things off
        extract($args);
    }//function widget
    // run a query if on a page
    public function gdd_Events_Register_Widget() {
        register_widget('gdd_Events_Widget');
    }


public function form( $instance ) {

    if ( isset( $instance[ 'eventsdropdown' ] ) )
    $selectedvalue = $instance[ 'eventsdropdown' ];
    else
    $selectedvalue = __( '', 'text-domain' );

    global $event;
    global $events;       
    global $wpdb;  
    global $depth;

     $events = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id, event FROM mo_events",ARRAY_A);
     ?>
    event
     <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('event'); ?>">Select an Event</label> <br>
     <select class="dropdown" id="eventsdropdown" name="eventsdropdown" title="Events Dropdown">

    <?php  
     foreach ($events as $event) {?>
             <option value=" <?php echo $event['id'] ?>"><?php echo $event['event']; ?></option>;
    </select>    

    <?php
    }   

   ?>  
    <label for="newevent">Enter a new event name:</label><br><br>
    <input type="text" id="newevent" newevent="mewevent"</inpUt><br><br> <?
  } // function form    
} //class
```

Can anyone show me  the error of my ways and what to do to get it to work?

Thanks Dan'l

Comment: You have to put the closing `</SELECT>` out of the loop.    `<?php  
     foreach ($events as $event) {?>
             <option value=" <?php echo $event['id'] ?>"><?php echo $event['event']; ?></option>;
    <?php
    }   ?>
    </select> <?php `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php  
 foreach ($events as $event) {?>
         <option value=" <?php echo $event['id'] ?>"><?php echo $event['event']; ?></option>;
</select>    

<?php
}
```

please put  tag outside of foreach loop

```
<?php  
 foreach ($events as $event) {?>
         <option value=" <?php echo $event['id'] ?>"><?php echo $event['event']; ?></option>;

<?php
} ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Your answer needs one more php close tag, right after the }, otherwise perfect. Thanks!